# How can I uninstall Safari Technology Preview?

Tags: safari, macos

I installed [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/), but want to get rid of it now. Clicking and holding on Launchpad doesn't do the trick, STP "wiggles" without a cross. The download is an installer, so I'm wondering if anyone knows of an uninstaller. Else I guess I'll just dump it in the trash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Exactly.** To delete an Application that is not sandboxed (not downloaded from App Store) you have to go in `/Applications/` and delete the Application File.

Comment: Will this stop Mac App Store update notifications?  I honestly forget how I first got theSafari Technology Preview, but I now get update notifications from the Mac App Store.  I no longer use it; will just deleting the App stop the update notifications from the App store?

Comment: I don't have it there ATM but I believe yes, the App Store should not notify you for updates of deleted apps.

Comment: Confirmed, after I used AppCleaner to remove all traces of it, the Mac App Store stopped showing that I had an update available.

Comment: @EricS. Where do you find AppCleaner? It's not part of Mac OS Catalina

Comment: It's a free, third-party utility: http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

Comment: FYI there's a situation where you cannot delete the app from the Application folder. You'll get a message like: The item "Safari Technology Preview" can't be moved to the Trash because some of its extensions are in use. In that case you can delete the app from the terminal with `sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Safari Technology Preview.app"`

Answer (score 10):

I used AppCleaner.app to make sure I don't have any leftovers. And it turned out there were a lot, namely crash reports, plists, diagnostics, cookies and more.

Just make sure no Safari files are included in the list of files about to be deleted. In my case there were no such files, it was either plugin related crash reports (e.g. VLC plugin) or other files clearly related to Safari Technology Preview.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on AppCleaner.  I've been looking for something like that.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend an app cleaner or uninstaller. You ca usually use the free versions from the App Store.