# Downgrade from Safari 12 to Safari 11

Tags: macos, safari, time-machine, voiceover

How can I downgrade from Safari 12 back to Safari 11?

I’m a blind Mac user, using Voiceover. Safari 12 has various accessibility bugs and thus I need to go back to the latest version of Safari 11.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far: restoring a previous version of my computer from a Time Machine backup. But that didn’t work, because as soon as the system restarted Safari updated automatically, before I could do basically anything.

Any other suggestions?

I’m running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: From what I have seen Safari has such deep hooks into macOS that you may have to reinstall High Sierra. You should be able to install a new version (then update to the latest version) right over your current OS and not lose any data. Do backup though, just in case.

Comment: Answered here [Downgrading from Safari beta](//apple.stackexchange.com/a/329972)

Comment: I’m going to close this since all the answers are more about how to do the initial restore which here is clear the OP (Lucas) has done and this is more about disabling / reversing the update. This answer shows how to disable SIP and revert the damage of an auto update. That also allows the OP to disable automatic updates / fix the damage / run without this one update for a while at least. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329972/5472

Comment: @bmike not the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path and so close.

Now just tell your system NOT to Auto update.

Open Apple Store in System Preference

and disable Auto update

[image]

**Alternative method:**

OK, lets use "sneaky" method,

Disconnect from Network, WIFI, (cut the cable ... just kidding :) so it can not update.

That should give you time to change the auto update settings.

Comment: The problem is: can I change the preference on a Time Machine backup? Because as soon as I recover from the backup, High Sierra automatically updates Safari. I’d have to change the setting before recovery.

Comment: OK, lets use "brute" method, disconnect from Network, WIFI, cut the cable :) so it can not update. That should give you time to change the auto update settings.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OP is a blind person, and I suspect his software cannot read what's on your attached screenshot.  Please care to better describe that dialog verbally, or copy down the text on it...

Comment: @MottiShneor , the OP just thanked me for providing a working solution. 
Simple yet effective. Thanks. – Lucas De Abreu Maia 18 hours ago

Comment: Indeed I am blind and thus the print screen was not helpful. The rest of the answer, though, was clear enough to made the image redundant.

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia I apologize for not paying attention.

Answer (score 3):

Go to [Mac App Store page](https://itunes.apple.com/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741) for macOS High Sierra and download the installer.

Create a bootable installer for macOS High Sierra by following the instructions in the support document, [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201372):

Use a USB flash drive with at-leat 12 GB of free storage space and run the following command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app
```

Once you have the installer ready, use it to install a fresh copy of macOS High Sierra. Once installed restore your data from Time Machine backup.

Now turn-off automatic updates in System Preferences and manually check for updates. Under Updates in Mac App Store **do not** choose to update Safari.

Comment: How is this different, if at all, from reinstalling MacOS from recovery mode?

Comment: It is almost same. What I am unsure about recovery is if it will also install the updates made available after 10.13.6 was released. If you download 10.13.6 from the App Store, you'll most certainly not get the updates (such as Safari 12) that were released subsequently.